# Reset temperature sensor on Supermicro X7DWA-N

Tags: supermicro, physical-environment

My supermicro X7DWA-N will no longer boot and the temperature light just blinks even when the system has been off for 12 hours, so it's not hot at all.

Is there a way to reset this alarm and perhaps letting the computer boot?

[image]

I wanted to try a CMOS reset, but I can't for the life of me find the jumper.

Comment: Copy and pasting the model number above led me right to [supermicro's page for that model](http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/Xeon1333/5400/X7DWA-N.cfm) which has a link to download the manual.  That manual tells you where the clear CMOS jumper is.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I did that as well, but that the jumper is not actually there on the board. Sorry I should have been clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

From your motherboard manual(X7DWA-N)

> JBT1 is used to clear CMOS. Instead of pins, this "jumper" consists of contact pads
> to prevent accidental clearing of CMOS. To clear CMOS, use a metal object such
> as a small screwdriver to touch both pads at the same time to short the connection.
> Always remove the AC power cord from the system before clearing CMOS.

And the jumper is located right above the Chassis Intrusion header. Here's the picture of the layout of your motherboard.

Answer (score 2):

i have a different board (X8DTN+) but i suspect that your "jumper" for resetting cmos may be similar. it is a "jumper" without pins so it is flat on the board. you would need to remove the battery and use e.g. a screwdriver gently to bridge the two points. the intention of supermicro is that we do not accidentally reset cmos (but it is more difficult to find the pinless "jumper"). look closer where your board manual indicates it, on mine it is next to the battery, good luck